# Организация процесса разработки веб приложения laravel + Vue/Nuxt?

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js, организация

Есть проект среднего объёма и команда разработчиков для бека и команда для фронта.
Я - фронтенд.
Приложение на стеке Laravel (REST API) + Vue.

Крутимся на виртуалке.

Для разработки фронт части необходимо разворачивать у себя на машине весь проект с базами данных и стартовать его при каждой активации WSL.
Докера, конечно, нет. Всё руками. Миллион команд, копипаст всяких .env и тому подобное.
Для винды используем Debian в WSL.
Обновляем фронт прода и dev`a с помощью композера, фронт идёт как просто пакет.

Для доступа к проекту локально нужно стучатся по адресу "https://[project_path].local".
Vue сборку при разработке собирает пакет для лары - laravel-mix - и кладёт собранные файлы в нужные папки, чтобы отдавать при заходе на локалку.

Всё это действо выглядит подозрительно.
Как можно избавится от необходимости разворачивать проект полностью в виртуалке на компах фронтенд разработчиков?
У нас есть dev сервер, где круглосуточно крутится приложение и есть некоторый запас ресурсов.

Интегрировать Swagger или аналоги так просто не выйдет.
Ну ладно, допустим, сейчас работаем и ладно, процессы так себе, но они работают.

Но сейчас встал вопрос о миграции на Nuxt.
Nuxt подымает свой dev сервер с функционалом, который сложнее, чем тот, что на dev сервере при работе с Vue-cli.

К тому-же, для полноценного SSR нужен именно развёрнутый нодовский сервер, который сам принимает запросы на страницы.

Как организовать структуру проекта?

Спасибо!